# Get boolean return from another program for if statement Nginx

Tags: perl, nginx

To Block access to wp-admin for all others countries, just accept my country, also blocked proxy.
I have a app Perl, who return a boolean true when for example is other_country_or_proxy()

To avoid compile nginx with geoip I want to just used perl in nginx, so sudo apt install nginx-extras (ngx_http_perl_module)

nginx.conf:

```
http {

   perl_modules /mnt/f/lib;
   perl_require App.pm;
```

example.com.conf:

```
location ~ ^/(wp-admin|wp-login.php) {

     perl App::handler;

 }


location / {

    autoindex on;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}


location ~ \.php$ {

    fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/example_example.com_php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /public_html/$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;

}
```

App::handler:

```
use nginx;
use Geo::IP2Proxy;

sub handler {
    my $r = shift;

    my $obj = Geo::IP2Proxy->open("/mnt/f/App/IP2PROXY.BIN");

     my $isproxy = $obj->isProxy("1.1.1.1");

    $r->send_http_header("text/html");
    return OK if $r->header_only;

    if ( $isproxy ) {
      $r->print("bad!\n<br/>");
    }
    else{
      $r->print("good!\n<br/>");
    }
    

    return OK;
}
```

The above code work, I get print the result string in example.com/wp-login.php

but I want something like this:

```
location ~ ^/(wp-admin|wp-login.php) {  

     if( perl App::handler ){ **(I need this)**
         return 503;
     }
     if not continue normal request php  **(I need this)**
 }


 sub handler {
     my $r = shift;

     my $obj = Geo::IP2Proxy->open("/mnt/f/App/IP2PROXY.BIN");

      my $isproxy = $obj->isProxy("1.1.1.1");


     if ( $isproxy ) {
       return "1";
     }

     return "0";
     

 }
```

Comment: [This](https://shortcut.com/developer-how-to/how-to-use-internal-redirects-in-nginx) would solve your problem. (Python is used, but Perl could be used just as easily.)